# problem signed char c++

Tags: c++, char, hex

This is the code:

```
int main()
{

 char c = 0x00;
 //c |= 0x0A;
 c |= 0xA0;

 while(c != 0x00)
 {
  cout << (c & 1) << endl;
  c = (c >> 1); 
 }
}
```

Why does this code work when I do `or` with `0X0A` and not with `0xA0`, as a number 0xA0 is to big to fit a signed char but why am I not allowed to set the bits for 0xA0?

When I print the loop it never breaks and it only print ones? How come?

Comment: It prints ones, because you're telling it to (`c & 1`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because of the sign extension of when performing a right shift.

```
0xA0 <=>        10100000 binary (and is a negative number because the MSB is set to 1)
(0xA0 >> 1) <=> 11010000
```

replace `char c` by `unsigned char c`
or mask the MSB after the shift.

```
int main()
{

 char c = 0x00;
 //c |= 0x0A;
 c |= 0xA0;

 while(c != 0x00)
 {
  cout << (c & 1) << endl;
  c = (c >> 1) & 0x7f; 
 }
}
```

Note that `char` is usually a signed (range -128..127) but some c/C++ compiler define `char` as `unsigned` (AIX xlC compiler is known case).

Comment: `(0xA0 >> 1) <=> 11010000` isn't necessarily right - it's implementation defined.

Comment: Yes I know, but it depends mainly if the value is signed or unsigned. I do not know a compiler that do not perform a sign extension on signed when performing a right shift.

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation must add a 1 in the most significant bit when right-shifting a negative number (the operator's behaviour is implementation defined, so usually depends on which CPU instructions are available).

```
0xA0 = 1010 0000 binary
```

The first time you sample `c & 1` - the least significant bit - it's actually a 0.  Then...

```
c = (c >> 1)
```

...shifts this to 1101 0000, then 1110 1000, 1111 0111, 1111 1011, 1111 1101, 1111 1110, 1111 1111 - which is then stable and never changes further.  Hence, you keep printing 1s and never satisfy the termination condition of c == 0.

> When I print the loop it never breaks and it only print ones? How come?

Well, it will have printed a few 0s at the very start, but your screen's probably scrolled past them in a blink and thereafter you only see the 1s.